# How to store Images/videos of users

Tags: express, authentication, jwt, backend

I'm building an app where users can post images and videos, I am doing it just for fun and I will limit the number of posts(10-15 maximum) adding to it the profiles' images of the users. Since I don't want to use a 3rd party server to store images in it, I thought about saving them in my Backend(backend and frontend are on the same server as well).

For my Authentication system, I am using JWT and have the middleware ready for use, for backend I am using expressjs.

Things I tried:

```
app.use(auth, express.static('./assets'));
```

But that didn't work for 2 reasons:

1- It DIDN'T work and I don't even know why(http requests were not going through).

2- Even if it works, this will give any logged in user the right to view all the assets, While I don't plan to make any posts Private, but I would like to learn how is that done(maybe a check from the frontend before sending the request?)

Comment: Are you using route???

Comment: @SangLe What route?